# TarsosDSP live delay and pitch change in voice Android

Tags: java, android, delay, pitch, tarsosdsp

I am trying to create an Android application that will allow the user to talk and hear their voice live and also add a delay and change the pitch of that voice in real time through two seekbars. I am currenlty trying to o in with TarsosDSP library in API30 android studio. If you have any othe suggestions please provide them.

I tried creating a thread and inside that thread with the android method audio record i will record from the mic the sound into small pieces and then will playback them in a loop make it seem like it never stops or is cut. then for the delay effect i just made a seekbar and converted the value in to millis and made that thread sleep using java. THis is where i stopped.

If anyone could help that will be great!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.